# jquery with validation plugin not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

After having spent hours trying to solve a seemingly simple problem (being walking through stackoverflow questions...), here I am once more obliged to turn to stackoverflow and submit my issue...I have a very basic form just two controls: a text input and a submit bottom. I am trying to get the jquery validation plugin to work. Here is my code:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
```

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function () {

        $('#frm').validate({

            rules: {
                txtInput: {
                    required:"Reuired"
                }
            },
            messages:{
                txtInput:"Please enter your first name"
            }
        });

    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="frm" name="frm" method="post">
        <div>
            <input id="txtInput" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <br />    
        <input id="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Submit" />
    </form>    

    </body>
    </html>
```

jquery.validate.js is version 1.11.1

My understanding is that if i submit the form with blank text input I must receive the message "Please enter your first name". But nothing happens and the form submits normally.
I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. The case is fairly simple. Thank you in advance for whatever help and/or direction you may give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this:

```
 <input id="txtInput" type="text" placeholder="Name"  name="txtInput"/>
```

Please note that I've added `name` attribute to the `input`,also update the `required` rule to true as :

```
rules: {
   txtInput: {
      required: true
   }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bau22/4/)

Comment: Hello back. Your suggestion seems to have worked. I have added 'name=txtInput' and now I can see the error message. Only it seems that it has no style applied to it (its color is black instead of red). I am going to dig deeper see if i can fix it. Thank you, it has put me in the right direction

Comment: @seyaobey Great news,if you need help then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the documentation, you are not using the required method properly, required takes either a true or false, or you can use it as an expression such as `#agree:checked`. [Validate Docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method)
@Vikram - correct, name attribute is what it's looking for.

```
$(function () {

    $('#frm').validate({

        rules: {
            txtInput: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages:{
            txtInput:"Please enter your first name"
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Z37f/5/)

```
$(function () {               
 $('#frm').validate({

        rules: {
            txtInput: {
                required:true
            }
        },
        messages:{
            txtInput:"Please enter your first name"
        }
    });

});
```